# Can connect to my tomcat home page but not to my GWT server homepage

Tags: gwt

I have what I think is a security setting problem.  I have an instance of tomcat running on my Win7 pc listening on 8080 and I can connect fine to it from another pc.
I then have a GWT app running listening on port 8888 but I can't connect to it.  Is there a setting on Win7 that I must white list what ports I want to allow remote connections to come in on.  I turned my firewall off momentarily but this made no difference.

Comment: Can you run tomcat on 8888 and connect? Can you run GWT on 8080 and connect? Is the GWT app running in dev-mode? Then you need access to the code-srv port as well.

Answer (score 1):

When Dev Mode starts, by default it does not allow access to your server from a remote IP. To active this, you must specify which address the server should bind to. From https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#What_options_can_be_passed_to_development_mode this is usually done by adding the following to your arguments, sometime before the modules

```
-bindAddress 0.0.0.0
```

This will bind the server to all IP addresses available to the JVM.